TAR output in a single folder for all the files scattered in different folder
I want to tar many files scattered across different folders into a single output folder. Although the folders are named differently, all the files inside have a .bz2 extension.
How can I do this?

What should the paths in the final tarball look like? Provide some example file paths, for the files and the target directory, and the paths in the resulting tarball

I am assuming you want to tar many files scattered across different folders into a single output file. If so, the following should work.
cd TOPLEVELDIR
tar cvf MyFile.tar `find . -name '*.bz2' -print`

where TOPLEVELDIR is the top level directory that contains all of the files you wish to capture. This is assuming there are no spaces in any of the file or directory names. It gets a bit trickier otherwise.

Not just spaces, but glob characters like [,], *, ?, etc. as well.
